# Viscosity solutions of $(-\Delta)^s u = 0$ in $\Omega $ with non-homogeneous data $u = 1$ in $\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, viscosity-solutions

Let us consider a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and the problem
$$
(1) \quad \begin{cases}
(-\Delta)^s u +\lambda u= 0 & x \in \Omega \\
u = 1 & x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lambda >0$ and the fractional Laplacian
ia $$ (-\Delta )^{s}u(x)=c_{n,s}\int \limits _{\mathbb {R} ^{n}}{{\frac {u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}}\,dy}$$
with $$ {\displaystyle c_{n,s}={\frac {4^{s}\Gamma (n/2+s)}{\pi ^{n/2}|\Gamma (-s)|}}}$$
I know several references with data $u(x) \equiv 0$ for $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega$, but where can I find a proof for existence and uniqueness of viscosity solutions to the problem above?
Also, is it true that the problem above is equivalent to
$$
(2)\quad \begin{cases}
(-\Delta)^s v + \lambda v = \underbrace{- \lambda \mathbf{1}_{\Omega^c}}_{=0}  + c_{n,s} \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-n-2s} dz & x \in \Omega \\
v = 0 & x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
i.e. that the change of variables $v = u-\mathbf{1}_{\Omega^c} $ can be performed to reduce the original problem to one with homogeneous data and a source term?

Comment: What is your motivation for this? Are you interested in viscosity solutions to equations involving the fractional Laplacian in general? I ask because $u \equiv 1$ is the (unique) strong solution

Comment: @JackT Thank you! I've added a lower order term (which was the original model I had in mind)

Comment: Why not simply consider $v = 1-u$, which solves $(-\Delta)^s v + \lambda v = \lambda$ in $\Omega$, with homogeneous Dirichlet condition $v = 0$ in $\Omega^c$? The unique solution of the latter is given by $$v(x) = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \lambda e^{-\lambda t} p_t^\Omega(x, y) dy dt,$$ where $p_t^\Omega(x,y)$ is the corresponding heat kernel.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks. Then, for $u$ we have $u(x) = 1- \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \lambda e^{-\lambda t} p_t^{\Omega}(x,y) dy dt$. Can we write this in a more compact way? Also, why the heat kernel and not the Green function of the fractional Laplacian?

Comment: @Zac: The integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} p_t^\Omega(x,y)dt$ is precisely the Green function for $(-\Delta)^s + \lambda$, or the $\lambda$-Green function for $(-\Delta)^s$. A "more compact way" to write this is, for example, $u(x) = \mathbb E^x e^{-\lambda \tau}$, where $\tau$ is the hitting time of $\Omega^c$ for the isotropic $2s$-stable Lévy process. :-)

Comment: Thank you! A couple of follow up questions: (1) Why is $u(x) = \mathbb{E}^x e^{-\lambda \tau}$? (I'm quite ignorant about probability theory--do you have a reference for this?). (2) Is it possible to rewrite it more compactly in analytic terms? I was thinking something like using $\int_\Omega p_t^{\Omega} dx = 1$ (is this true in the fractional case too?) (3) Can you give me a reference about the fact that the integral is the Green function of $(-\Delta)^s + \lambda$?.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I forgot to tag you in the follow-up questions in the comment above

Comment: @Zac: Regarding (2), unless $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$, we have $\int_\Omega p^\Omega_t(x,y)dy < 1$ both in the classical case ($s=1$) and in the fractional case ($0<s<1$). I am not aware of a simpler way to define the $\lambda$-Green function, even in the classical case. For (3), this is a general fact in the theory of semigroups of operators, any reference on that subject will do. An answer to (1) is more involved: this is a potential-theoretic fact, and in potential theory one usually tends not to use the generator whenever possible (except perhaps when discussing *local* operators). (...)

Comment: (...) It is quite straightforward to chech that $u(x)=\mathbb E^xe^{-\lambda \tau}$ satisfies $Lu=-\lambda u$, where $L$ is the *Dynkin's characteristic operator*. Boundary continuity of this $u$ follows from general facts about solutions of the Dirichlet problem. It remains to ask whether the Dynkin's characteristic operator is the same as $-(-\Delta)^s$. The answer is affirmative, but this is not entirely straightforward; for a partial discussion the relation between these two operators you may have a look at my survey at https://doi.org/10.1515/fca-2017-0002

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you so much. My confusion about (2) comes from this: formally, combining the approach in the OP and your comment, we should get $$u(x) = \int_\Omega \left(\int_{0}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} p_t^\Omega(x,y) dt\right) f(y) dy,$$ where $f(y) = c_{n,s} \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dz $. How can this shown to be the same as $u(x) = 1- \int_0^\infty\int_\Omega \lambda e^{-\lambda t}p_t^\Omega(x,y) dydt$?

Comment: @Zac: This is called the *Ikeda–Watanabe formula* in the probability literature: the joint distribution of $(\tau, X_{\tau-}, X_\tau)$ is given by $p^\Omega_t(x, y) \nu(y,z) dt dy dz$, where $\nu(y,z) = c_{n,s} |y-z|^{-n-2s}$. From the PDE point of view, technical details aside, this is fairly straightforward, and you essentially described the argument in your question, did you not?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Yes, but the final result is surprising to me: I don't see how to show $$\int_\Omega \left( \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} p_t^\Omega(x,y) dt \right) f(y) dy = 1 - \int_\Omega \left( \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} p_t^\Omega(x,y) dt\right) dy$$ directly

Comment: @Zac: Too long for a comment, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I you are not really interested about viscosity solutions, but just the "philosophical reason" why the solution of the problem with inhomogeneous exterior condition can be written in terms of the heat kernel (as suggested by the comments), here is an answer.

Choose $z \notin \overline\Omega$ and define
$$ u_z(x) = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega e^{-\lambda t} p^\Omega_t(x, y) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy dt , $$
where $p^\Omega$ is the heat kernel for $(-\Delta)^s$ in $\Omega$, with zero condition in $\Omega^c$. Then, formally,
$$ \begin{aligned} (-\Delta)^s u_z(x) & = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega e^{-\lambda t} (-\Delta_x)^s p^\Omega_t(x, y) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy dt \\ & = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega e^{-\lambda t} (-\tfrac\partial{\partial t}) p^\Omega_t(x, y) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy dt . \end{aligned} $$
Add $\lambda u_z$:
$$ \begin{aligned} ((-\Delta)^s + \lambda) u_z(x) & = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega e^{-\lambda t} (-\tfrac\partial{\partial t} + \lambda) p^\Omega_t(x, y) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy dt \\ & = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega (-\tfrac\partial{\partial t}) (e^{-\lambda t} p^\Omega_t(x, y)) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy dt \\ & = \int_\Omega p^\Omega_0(x, y) c_{n,s} |y - z|^{-n-2s} dy = c_{n,s} |x - z|^{-n-2s} . \end{aligned} $$
The function $u_z$ is known as the $\lambda$-Poisson kernel for $(-\Delta)^s$ in $\Omega$; if $\lambda = 0$, this is just the Poisson kernel.

Now define $$v(x) = \int_{(\overline\Omega)^c} \lambda u_z(x) dz$$ for $x \in \Omega$. By the above calculation,
$$((-\Delta)^s + \lambda) v(x) = \int_{(\overline\Omega)^c} c_{n,s} \lambda |x - z|^{-n-2s} dz .$$
In other words, if $u(x) = v(x)$ for $x \in \Omega$ and $u(x) = \lambda$ otherwise, then
$$((-\Delta)^s + \lambda) u(x) = 0 ,$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful. I still have some follow-up questions, which I've included in the text of the bounty opened above

Comment: there are some typos in the text unfortunately, I meant $\mathbf 1_{\Omega^c}$  and $v=u-\mathbf{1}_{\Omega^c}$ above